# Certain properties of this complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function

$\frac{e^z}{z^2 (z-3)}$

There are a few things I need to find/show:

a) The radius of convergence of its Taylor expansion around z=i

b) All it's poles and residues

c) The contour integral of it about |z| =1

Here's what I've done so far:

a) This is really the part I don't completely understand. Is there some way to use that the function is analytic in an open disk around z=i so it's Taylor series converges on that disk?

b) The poles are at zero and three; at three, the residue  at three is $e^3 /3$ I think and at zero is 1/9; I think I understand this part but let me know if I'm wrong!

c) If my answer to (b) was correct, I think that would make the answer to this $\frac{2\pi i}{9}$ if I understand this

Answer (score 0):

a) The radius of convergence of the Taylor series centered at $i$ is $1$: it's the distance from $i$ to the nearest pole, which is $0$.

b) The residue at $3$ is $\frac{e^3}9$ and the residue at $0$ is $-\frac49$.

c) The integral is equal to$$2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=-\frac{8\pi i}9.$$